# Ubuntu on Raspberry PI

Tags: display, menu

The Help menu and Google Account login are both scrambled. Running on a raspberry Pi 4 with the latest Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS The screen display is OK otherwise.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean scrambled? Can you provide a screenshot to clarify further?

Comment: Scrambled as if the text is smeared illegible out in broken lines - don't know how to get screenshot.

Comment: I have tried this on a new install for a Raspberry Pi model 4B and got the same problem.

Comment: And on a different monitor!